# Reading and Writing from a csv file: want to only extract rows that do not contain zeros

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write a program to pull information from a file, but i only want the rows that do not contain 0. I know how to get the file to print to screen but I can't seem to get the desired rows printed with out printing each individual line I want. I've tried putting the information i want into a list and writing it to a new CSV file but it just jumbles everything up into 2 rows instead of the 300+ I'm trying to get. Any help would be appreciated

```
Months   A    B    C

Feb-49   0     0     0

Jan-50   95    378   3767

Feb-50   67    17    233

Jan-51   0     0     0

Feb-51   0     0     0

#This file has about 400 rows that look something like this
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be nice if you could show us your code. This way we can help you better. Besides that it shows that you already put in some work which good for receiving quality answers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.